# How to save self-trained word2vec to a txt file with format like 'word2vec-google-news' or 'glove.6b.50d'

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

I wonder that how can I save a self-trained word2vec to txt file with the format like 'word2vec-google-news' or 'glove.6b.50d' which has the tokens followed by matched vectors.[image: .]

I export my self-trained vectors to txt file which only has vectors but no tokens in the front of those vectors.
[image]

My code for training my own word2vec:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import collections
import math
import random
import numpy as np
from six.moves import xrange
import zipfile
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

filename = ('data/data.zip')

# Step 1: Read the data into a list of strings.
def read_data(filename):
  with zipfile.ZipFile(filename) as f:
    data = tf.compat.as_str(f.read(f.namelist()[0])).split()
    return data

words = read_data(filename)
#print('Data size', len(words))


# Step 2: Build the dictionary and replace rare words with UNK token.
vocabulary_size = 50000
def build_dataset(words):
    count = [['UNK', -1]]
    count.extend(collections.Counter(words).most_common(vocabulary_size - 1))
    #print("count",len(count))
    dictionary = dict()
    for word, _ in count:
        dictionary[word] = len(dictionary)
    data = list()
    unk_count = 0
    for word in words:
        if word in dictionary:
            index = dictionary[word]
        else:
            index = 0
            unk_count += 1
        data.append(index)
    count[0][1] = unk_count
    reverse_dictionary = dict(zip(dictionary.values(), dictionary.keys()))
    return data, count, dictionary, reverse_dictionary

data, count, dictionary, reverse_dictionary = build_dataset(words)

#del words  # Hint to reduce memory.
#print('Most common words (+UNK)', count[:5])
#print('Sample data', data[:10], [reverse_dictionary[i] for i in data[:10]])



data_index = 0

# Step 3: Function to generate a training batch for the skip-gram model.
def generate_batch(batch_size, num_skips, skip_window):
    global data_index
    assert batch_size % num_skips == 0
    assert num_skips <= 2 * skip_window
    batch = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size), dtype=np.int32)
    labels = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size, 1), dtype=np.int32)
    span = 2 * skip_window + 1  # [ skip_window target skip_window ]
    buffer = collections.deque(maxlen=span)
    for _ in range(span):
        buffer.append(data[data_index])
        data_index = (data_index + 1) % len(data)
    for i in range(batch_size // num_skips):
        target = skip_window  # target label at the center of the buffer
        targets_to_avoid = [skip_window]
        for j in range(num_skips):
            while target in targets_to_avoid:
                target = random.randint(0, span - 1)
            targets_to_avoid.append(target)
            batch[i * num_skips + j] = buffer[skip_window]
            labels[i * num_skips + j, 0] = buffer[target]
        buffer.append(data[data_index])
        data_index = (data_index + 1) % len(data)
    return batch, labels

batch, labels = generate_batch(batch_size=8, num_skips=2, skip_window=1)
#for i in range(8):
 #print(batch[i], reverse_dictionary[batch[i]],'->', labels[i, 0], reverse_dictionary[labels[i, 0]])

# Step 4: Build and train a skip-gram model.
batch_size = 128
embedding_size = 128
skip_window = 2
num_skips = 2
valid_size = 9
valid_window = 100
num_sampled = 64    # Number of negative examples to sample.
valid_examples = np.random.choice(valid_window, valid_size, replace=False)

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    # Input data.
    train_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size])
    train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])
    valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_examples, dtype=tf.int32)

    # Ops and variables pinned to the CPU because of missing GPU implementation
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        # Look up embeddings for inputs.
        embeddings = tf.Variable(
            tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))
        embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_inputs)

        # Construct the variables for the NCE loss
        nce_weights = tf.Variable(
            tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                                stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))
        nce_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]),dtype=tf.float32)

    # Compute the average NCE loss for the batch.
    # tf.nce_loss automatically draws a new sample of the negative labels each
    # time we evaluate the loss.
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(
            tf.nn.nce_loss(weights=nce_weights,biases=nce_biases, inputs=embed, labels=train_labels,
                 num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size))

    # Construct the SGD optimizer using a learning rate of 1.0.
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)

    # Compute the cosine similarity between minibatch examples and all embeddings.
    norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(embeddings), 1, keep_dims=True))
    normalized_embeddings = embeddings / norm
    valid_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(normalized_embeddings, valid_dataset)
    similarity = tf.matmul(valid_embeddings, normalized_embeddings, transpose_b=True)

    # Add variable initializer.
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Step 5: Begin training.
num_steps = 20000

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
    # We must initialize all variables before we use them.
    init.run()
    #print("Initialized")

    average_loss = 0
    for step in xrange(num_steps):
        batch_inputs, batch_labels = generate_batch(batch_size, num_skips, skip_window)
        feed_dict = {train_inputs: batch_inputs, train_labels: batch_labels}

        # We perform one update step by evaluating the optimizer op (including it
        # in the list of returned values for session.run()
        _, loss_val = session.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        average_loss += loss_val

        #if step % 2000 == 0:
         #   if step > 0:
          #      average_loss /= 2000
            # The average loss is an estimate of the loss over the last 2000 batches.
           # print("Average loss at step ", step, ": ", average_loss)
            #average_loss = 0

    final_embeddings = normalized_embeddings.eval()


np.savetxt('data/w2v.txt', final_embeddings)
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Doesn't it working fine?

Comment: The code works fine for word embedding. However, the vectors I pulled out to the txt file which doesn't have matched vocabularies at the beginning of the vectors (showed in second graph). I'd like the txt file contains vocabularies following with its vectors just like the format of 'word2vec-google-news' or 'glove.6b.50d' (showed in the first graph). Cause I need it that format for training my another model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at the implementation of `_save_word2vec_format()` in `gensim` for an example of Python code which writes that format:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/e859c11f6f57bf3c883a718a9ab7067ac0c2d4cf/gensim/models/utils_any2vec.py#L104

```py
def _save_word2vec_format(fname, vocab, vectors, fvocab=None, binary=False, total_vec=None):
    """Store the input-hidden weight matrix in the same format used by the original
    C word2vec-tool, for compatibility.
    Parameters
    ----------
    fname : str
        The file path used to save the vectors in.
    vocab : dict
        The vocabulary of words.
    vectors : numpy.array
        The vectors to be stored.
    fvocab : str, optional
        File path used to save the vocabulary.
    binary : bool, optional
        If True, the data wil be saved in binary word2vec format, else it will be saved in plain text.
    total_vec : int, optional
        Explicitly specify total number of vectors
        (in case word vectors are appended with document vectors afterwards).
    """
    if not (vocab or vectors):
        raise RuntimeError("no input")
    if total_vec is None:
        total_vec = len(vocab)
    vector_size = vectors.shape[1]
    if fvocab is not None:
        logger.info("storing vocabulary in %s", fvocab)
        with utils.open(fvocab, 'wb') as vout:
            for word, vocab_ in sorted(iteritems(vocab), key=lambda item: -item[1].count):
                vout.write(utils.to_utf8("%s %s\n" % (word, vocab_.count)))
    logger.info("storing %sx%s projection weights into %s", total_vec, vector_size, fname)
    assert (len(vocab), vector_size) == vectors.shape
    with utils.open(fname, 'wb') as fout:
        fout.write(utils.to_utf8("%s %s\n" % (total_vec, vector_size)))
        # store in sorted order: most frequent words at the top
        for word, vocab_ in sorted(iteritems(vocab), key=lambda item: -item[1].count):
            row = vectors[vocab_.index]
            if binary:
                row = row.astype(REAL)
                fout.write(utils.to_utf8(word) + b" " + row.tostring())
            else:
                fout.write(utils.to_utf8("%s %s\n" % (word, ' '.join(repr(val) for val in row))))
```